# Question about inversion of adjective

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, inversion

> Strong as he was he could beat his opponent.

I saw the above sentence on a website which explains the usage of inversion. It gives the previous example.  Is this equal to:

> Though he was strong he could not beat his opponent.

Comment: Did you accidentally leave out the word *not* in the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the the two sentences you list are not equivalent. The meaning of the first sentence is actually "because he was very strong, he was able to defeat his opponent".

I looked up [the source of the quote](https://www.englishpractice.com/improve/inversion-adjectives-adverbs/), and I suspect that the author of the article made a typo in that sentence because the rest of their examples make sense but this one does not.

The proper equivalent to the second sentence would be:

> Strong as he was, he could **not** beat his opponent.

This has the negation, which the example sentence they give does not.